# using joins connect two or more tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, join

I have two types of table called **Organizations** and **OrgLogin.**

**Organizations:**

```
ID
Name
```

**OrgLogin:**

```
LoginId
UserName
Password
```

I want to make select query with username and password in Organizations Table. So I used Joins.

My query is,

```
select top(55)'Insert into Organizations(Id,Username,Password,Name)values(' + 
       Cast(o.organizationId as varchar(50))+',''' +
        IsNull(''''+ol.UserName+'''', 'NULL')+','+
       isnull(convert(nvarchar(max),HASHBYTES('MD5',ol.Password),1),'NULL')+ ')' 
    FROM Organization AS o 
    left join OrgLogin As ol ON ol.LoginId=o.OrganizationID
```

I have the result set following,

```
Insert into Organizations(Id,CreateDate,Username,Password)values(1,'NULL,NULL)

Insert into Organizations(Id,CreateDate,Username,Password)values(2,'NULL,NULL)

Insert into Organizations(Id,CreateDate,Username,Password)values(3,'NULL,NULL)

Insert into Organizations(Id,CreateDate,Username,Password)values(4,'NULL,NULL)

Insert into Organizations(Id,CreateDate,Username,Password)values(5,''V EX Electronics Systems Pvt.Ltd.Chennai',0xACB3BB721E1EC47C4CB569331ACC4E8E)

Insert into Organizations(Id,CreateDate,Username,Password)values(5,''V EX Electronics Systems Pvt.Ltd.Chennai',0xACB3BB721E1EC47C4CB569331ACC4E8E)
```

Id's are repeating see '5' Id. Two times created. why it is happening? any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should tidy up the single quotes (before the first ISNULL)

```
select top(55)'
    Insert into Organizations(Id,Username,Password,Name)values(' + 
    Cast(o.organizationId as varchar(50))+',' +
    IsNull(''''+ol.UserName+'''', 'NULL')+','+
    isnull(convert(nvarchar(max),HASHBYTES('MD5',ol.Password),1),'NULL')+ ')' 
FROM Organization AS o 
left join OrgLogin As ol ON ol.LoginId=o.OrganizationID
```

Next, `o.id` will repeat whenever there is more than one OrgLogin record for that organization.

Comment: so how to avoid o.id should not repeat. Because Organizationid is unique.